# Linked lists matrix Python

Tags: python, matrix, linked-list

I´m trying to make a 19x19 matrix with a Object Chip() in each square:

```
rows = Linked_list()
Column = Linked_list()
for p in range(0, 19):
    self.rows.new_node(Chip())
for j in range(0, 19):
    Column.new_node(rows)
```

But when I search for the column Node 1 it doesn't return me a linked list but the object Chip instead... any ideas on how i could make a matrix using linked lists or why this keeps failing?

Comment: What's `Linked_list` class?

Comment: @ozgur" def __init__(self):
        self.son = None
        self.father = None

    def add_node(self, value):
        if not self.father:
            self.father = Node(value)
            self.son = self.father
        else:
            self.son.next = Node(value)
            self.son = self.son.next

    def obtain(self, position):
        node = self.father
        for i in range(position):
            if node:
                node = node.next
        if not node:
            return "position not found"
        else:
            return node.value"